# How to make the effect of a div that covers an other div when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I make this effect of a div that covers an other div like this website for example: [Harbr](http://harbr.co/)

I had a few ideas using z-indexes but it feels like I am missing something. the content div may cover the div with the background-image, but I don't think it would make the "swallow" effect and I might be missing something with this process. If there is any tutorial that explanes this accurately I will be happy to get a link :)

Comment: Search term: parallax

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. It is not possible for us to give an answer to such a question

Comment: Tnx. Didnt know it has a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called parallax scrolling.

There are jQuery plugins available that do this for you:

[jQuery parallax scrolling plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/parallax/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use *background-attachment: fixed;* to lock the background-image, is a easy way to doing a parallax effect;

I use it on this website: [seniorti](http://www.seniorti.cl/)

Comment: Please don't use stack overflow just to your site. If you have a valid answer then you can post the answer, the code code and even maybe even slip-in your own site as _"by the way, here's an example of this in use"_, but just pointing somewhere else saying "this is used there" is an awful answer even if it wasn't self promotion.